# How does countering an attack / ability work in Arena 1v1

Tags: blade-and-soul

I know countering is different based on different class but in general, is countering based on the following and if not, then what:

1. Abilities that you have leveled up: Are counter options dependent on what abilities you have chosen?
2. Abilities that enemy has leveled up: Are your counters dependent on enemy abilities? Do your counter options change if the opponent does/doesn't have a particular ability?
3. Is countering based on RNG? There have been instances when I apparently countered an enemy ability while doing nothing.
4. Does counter always result in a stun? Does it do any damage in return?

Follow up question: Is countering (not evade or block) possible in PvE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer the follow up question first: There is no split between PvE, Open and Arena PvP as far as skills and game mechanics are concerned. The only difference is that in Arena PvP your gear does not matter.

1. Yes. If you open your skill book (the 'k' key), you can list the skills by the level they will be available to you. Also as you progress you will gain skill points that you can spend to modify your skills. For example the counter skill for KFMs (1) could be modified to give health on counter or to be an attack instead of defense. That brings us to second question.
2. Yes. Same as you, they will gain access to new skills and will be able to trait them. For example KFMs will get access to Triple Kick (RMB) which they could use to break enemy's defenses. For that reason most of the people you will meet in the Arena PvP will be at least level 45.
3. There are RNG based Evade and Block, those are based on your stats. The other option are skill based defenses.
4. No. Different classes have different counters. For example Warlock's block Quell (1) does no damage on its own. It will enable secondary skill Repulse (F) that could be used to knock you back. Checkout the https://bnstree.com/ to see the skills and popular PvP builds.